# OutofMemory Exception Details

Tags: jvm, out-of-memory

I was asked this question in a recent Java interview.
When we get an OutOfMemory Exception , how can we find out which class and which method has thrown OutOfMemory Exception. I answered that it will come in stack trace but he told me that many times it will not tell you which particular method/class has thrown that exception. I assume he was expecting some tool or JVM argument that can help. But I have never used it so I couldn't answer.

I tried a simple example where I am putting values in a hashmap in an infinite loop. After sometime I got an OutOfMemory error and it does show the class/method name and line number. I want to understand what are the scenarios where it will not give you these details[method/classname] and which tool/VM arguments I can use to find it out.

```
**Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.expandCapacity(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.ensureCapacityInternal(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(Unknown Source)
    at hashmapTest.main(hashmapTest.java:18)**
```

I have also read about this VM argument
Xms1024m -Xmx1024m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath but I am not very sure if it is use to achieve this purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Java is running out of heap space, you may see which particular object is throwing the exception if it's one of your own object, but it may very well be an internal Java object that it doing some low-level delayed internal work, in which case the trace in not very helpful.

The Xms option defines the maximum heap size allowed and the Xms option defines the minimum heap size, so it should resolve your problem if it's not a memory leak/overhead issue.

If you suspect your program to use a lot more memory than necessary, there are some tools out there to track the memory usage.